# How can I convert a CFStringRef to a String in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to convert a `CFStringRef` (`core_foundation::string::CFStringRef`) to a `String` (`std::string::String`).

[Documentation](https://docs.rs/core-foundation/0.9.4/core_foundation/string/type.CFStringRef.html) on `CFStringRef`.

Unfortunately I have no clue how to tackle this problem.

Comment: If I understand this type and library correctly then `CFStringRef` is basically a `*const c_void` representing a pointer to a NULL terminated C-string. So you probably could use something like [CStr::from_ptr](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html#method.from_ptr) and create `CStr` from it, which can later be converted to `String`.

Comment: I would probably [go through `CFString` and it's `Display` implementation](https://gist.github.com/rust-play/9ca921018c6cf966c182b7cbf3862ef0) in the hopes that it does know and properly handle it's underlying encoding, though I cannot test because of linking errors on [rustexplorer](https://www.rustexplorer.com)

Comment: It looks like there's a `From` implementation on `&'a CFString` that returns a `Cow<'a, str>` so if you use `CFString::from_void` to get a CFString you should be able to use that with `into_owned` to get a `String`.